# select where row contains string

Tags: php, mysql

I have a column named `software_hardware` from the table `activities` which could have multiple product inputs separated by a pipeline like `INVENTORY| POS |` or `GPOS | ACCOUNTING |`.

I have this query:

```
SELECT a.id, a.ticket_number, a.client, a.software_hardware, 
a.issues_concern, a.status, a.technical_programmer, a.date_added 
FROM activities a
WHERE a.client = '".$_POST['client']."' AND a.software_hardware LIKE '%".$arr[$i]."%'
ORDER BY date_added DESC
```

`$arr = explode("|", $_POST['Soft_hard']);`

When I select a client and a product, related info would be displayed on a div. Now my problem is, if I have `POS` and `GPOS`, I realized I couldn't use `LIKE '%[input product name here]%'`as this would return results that contains both `POS` and `GPOS` if I selected `POS`.

How can I fix this query to not display `GPOS` if I selected `POS`?

PS. I am aware of the issues with MySQL. It's what the company I'm in uses so I have no choice at the moment.

Comment: use like `AND a.software_hardware LIKE '".$arr[$i]."%'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`REGEXP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html):

```
a.software_hardware REGEXP '[[:<:]]" . $arr[$i] . "[[:>:]]'
```

the `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` markers stand for word boundaries. So `POS` cannot match `GPOS` as there would be no word boundary at the beginning.

Note you will need to `trim($arr[$i])` if it has leading or trailing whitespace.

Comment: oh wow I didn't know I could use regex on a query! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.id, a.ticket_number, a.client, a.software_hardware, 
a.issues_concern, a.status, a.technical_programmer, a.date_added 
FROM activities a
WHERE a.client = '".$_POST['client']."' 
AND UPPER(a.software_hardware) LIKE '%".strtoupper($arr[$i])."%'
ORDER BY a.date_added DESC
```